# 'command not found' after 'npm test' in express, when i try to implement (cf. jest, supertest, env)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to implement TESTCODE by jest and supertest in express.

but when i type `npm test` in vsc terminal, it made the following issue:

'.env' file already has private data. So it works when I try to signup and signin, but when i do `npm test` it made the issue.

I think it might because because jest(?) can't read `.env.` file properly.

**vsc terminal**

```
env-cmd ./.env jest --watch

./.env: line 1: DATABASE_USERNAME: command not found
./.env: line 2: DATABASE_PASSWORD: command not found
./.env: line 3: DATABASE_NAME: command not found
./.env: line 4: DATABASE_HOST: command not found
./.env: line 5: DATABASE_PORT: command not found
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd ./.env jest --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.9.2",
    "i18n": "^0.13.2",
    "i18n-express": "^1.1.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "superagent": "^6.1.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your test script and it worked but make sure:

1. Enough permission is granted for the project directory, run `chmod -R a+rwx /your/project/path`
2. File structure is correct

- project

  - .env
  - package.json

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

My file structure is
*project
 *server
  *.env
  *package.json
  
First time when I type ‘npm test’ it made this result 
=> ```spawn ./.env EACCES```

Comment: So I typed ‘chmod -R 777 server/ ‘, and ‘npm test’
Then  it made this result
=> 
``` > env-cmd ./.env jest --watch

./.env: line 1: DATABASE_USERNAME: command not found
./.env: line 2: DATABASE_PASSWORD: command not found
./.env: line 3: DATABASE_NAME: command not found
./.env: line 4: DATABASE_HOST: command not found
./.env: line 5: DATABASE_PORT: command not found
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```
Then I typed what you said ‘chmod -R a+rwx server/‘, and ‘npm test’
Then it made same result like up thing……….

Comment: If you do `npm init` in the project directory you might need to put the .env file and package.json file in the project directory since .env file only works in root directory

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice.

My file structure is

```
project
    server
        .env
        package.json
```

First time when I type ‘npm test’ it made this result
=> `spawn ./.env EACCES`

## So I typed ‘chmod -R 777 server/ ‘, and ‘npm test’
Then  it made this result

```
 > env-cmd ./.env jest --watch

./.env: line 1: DATABASE_USERNAME: command not found
./.env: line 2: DATABASE_PASSWORD: command not found
./.env: line 3: DATABASE_NAME: command not found
./.env: line 4: DATABASE_HOST: command not found
./.env: line 5: DATABASE_PORT: command not found
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Then I typed what you said ‘chmod -R a+rwx server/‘, and ‘npm test’
Then it made same result like up thing……….